# What exactly is doing ps -aux in terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, process, ps

Command ps statically lists all processes. What exactly is doing -aux option?

a - all processes

u - user

x - execute

Something more?

Comment: This would be a better question for [unix.se], [ubuntu.se], or https://superuser.com .

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

I found a nice explanation here: http://www.linfo.org/ps.html

> A common and convenient way of using ps to obtain much more complete information about the processes currently on the system is to use the following:
>
> ps -aux | less
>
> The -a option tells ps to list the processes of all users on the system rather than just those of the current user, with the exception of group leaders and processes not associated with a terminal. A group leader is the first member of a group of related processes.
>
> The -u option tells ps to provide detailed information about each process. The -x option adds to the list processes that have no controlling terminal, such as daemons, which are programs that are launched during booting (i.e., computer startup) and run unobtrusively in the background until they are activated by a particular event or condition.